# Good uses for leftover Bechamel?

Tags: sauce, culinary-uses

I guess it's technically a Mornay, it has Parmesan and Fontina. I've got about 1 1/2 cups in my fridge. Refrigerated it's solid enough to hold a knife vertically, when it was warm it was just barely pourable and self spreading. It's a darn good sauce, I'd hate to waste it, but after all my adventures lately making an 'ultimate' lasagna, I won't end up using it for pasta. I'd like to put it to use in an entirely different way, preferably with a totally different flavor profile.

Any ideas?

Bonus points if it would make a nice lunch for the day after the extreme lasagna dinner.

Comment: I have to vote to close as this is either an opinion based question or a poll, but you might try using it on a Croque-monsieur sandwich.  You might also join us in chat to discuss ideas.

Comment: I am giving you an upvote, not to say this is a good question, but because I think that will give you enough reputation to enter chat.

Comment: On the "related" questions list I see right now, there are a dozen that are "what can I do with leftover *blank*, many with several votes and answers. What makes this question any different?

Comment: As sites evolve over time, guidelines change and the older questions don't always get cleaned up or closed.  The existence of similar questions doesn't provide a precedent.  Sorry.  It is also possible my close vote will not be sustained.

Comment: Many of those related questions you see either are already closed, or should be. Our semi-official FAQ on this is [Can I ask about how to use a specific ingredient? (AKA: Culinary Uses Guidelines)](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/740). Basically, we try to limit these questions to those asking about very rare or traditionally non-culinary ingredients. We also didn't have [chat] back then, so the topic used to be a little more controversial.

Comment: @Aaronut Based on that FAQ, I would argue that a really nice Mornay sauce is sufficiently 'special' to warrant allowing the question. It's not like I'm asking how to use up all of the zucchini I've been recently gifted. As you know, I'm a newbie, but I'm starting to get a feel for the joint. SAJ14SAJ has already offered a pretty decent suggestion, but I'll have to Google it.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I wish you had suggested Croque-Monsiuer as an answer, because that is exactly what I am going to do. I had never heard of the concept, but upon Googling, it seems perfect. I would have "accepted" the answer and voted it up. I'm looking forward to the lunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crouque-Monsier or the similar "Hot Brown" sandwich is perfect for my needs. That will use up the sauce in a completely different way. It will also make a great lunch. Thanks SAJ14SAJ for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You're already half way towards [kroketten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croquette#Netherlands).

(Search for 'Dutch Croquettes' to find recipes in English)

Answer (score 0):

You can mix it with a little bit of tomatoes and pour it over spicy burritos the oven heat makes everything golden brown and crusty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something kind of healthy, you can always mix it with steamed spinach and it can't be more delicious!!! Oh, with brocoli works pretty well too ;-)